# React Pagination doesn't work after I fetch users with query parameters in my api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, web, pagination

I was following [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ajna-pagination-forked-7mrtq?file=/src/App.tsx) tutorial for React Pagination in TypeScript and I encountered some errors along the way. When I implement my own api and api query parameters in the fetch function the buttons for traversing the pages don't render anymore

Main.tsx:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState('');
    const [role, setRole] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [expire, setExpire] = useState<any>();
    const [usersTotal, setUsersTotal] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);
    // const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const history = useNavigate();

    const outerLimit = 2;
    const innerLimit = 2;

    const {
        pages,
        pagesCount,
        offset,
        currentPage,
        setCurrentPage,
        setIsDisabled,
        isDisabled,
        pageSize,
        setPageSize
    } = usePagination({
        total: usersTotal,
        limits: {
            outer: outerLimit,
            inner: innerLimit
        },
        initialState: {
            pageSize: 10,
            isDisabled: false,
            currentPage: 1
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        refreshToken();
        getUsers(pageSize, offset);
    }, [currentPage, pageSize, offset, token]);

    //...
const getUsers = async (
        pageSize: number,
        offset: number,
    ): Promise<any> => {
        if(role === 'super-admin'){
            const response = await axiosJWT.get(`http://localhost:5000/users/?limit=${pageSize}&?offset=${offset}`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
            setUsers(response.data);
            setUsersTotal(response.data.length);
        }
    }


    const handlePageChange = (nextPage: number): void => {
        setCurrentPage(nextPage);
        console.log("request new data with -> ", nextPage);
    };

    const handlePageSizeChange = (
        event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
    ): void => {
        const pageSize = Number(event.target.value);
        setPageSize(pageSize);
    }

    const handleDisableClick = (): void => {
        setIsDisabled((oldState) => !oldState);
    }
```

And then the other thing that's different than from the tutorial is a table with all users which is instead of the `<Grid>` element in the tutorial

```js
<TableContainer>
                        <Table size="lg" variant='striped'>
                            <TableCaption>
                                User Table
                            </TableCaption>

                            <Thead>
                                <Tr>
                                    <Th>
                                        ID
                                    </Th>
                                    <Th>
                                        Name
                                    </Th>
                                    <Th>
                                        Email
                                    </Th>
                                    <Th>
                                        Role
                                    </Th>
                                    <Th>
                                        Created At
                                    </Th>
                                    <Th>
                                        Updated At
                                    </Th>
                                </Tr>
                            </Thead>

                            <Tbody>
                                {users?.map((user) => (
                                    <Tr key={user.id}>
                                        <Td isNumeric>{user.id}</Td>
                                        <Td>{user.name}</Td>
                                        <Td>{user.email}</Td>
                                        <Td>{user.role}</Td>
                                        <Td>{user.createdAt}</Td>
                                        <Td>{user.updatedAt}</Td>
                                    </Tr>
                                ))}
                            </Tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to also include my `getUsers()` function from the API

Controllers/Users.js

```
export const getUsers = async (req, res) => {

    const limit = req.query.limit;
    const offset = req.query.offset;

    try {

        const options = {
            attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'role', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
        }

        if(limit){
            options.limit = Number(limit);
        }
        if(offset){
            options.offset = Number(offset);
        }

        const users = await Users.findAll(options);
        res.json(users);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, for example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: @NishargShah I understand now but I don’t have access to my computer at this very moment. But I believe I attached the link to the sandbox